# How to store action result and pass as http header

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2, swashbuckle, powerapps

Currently I'm trying to create a simple login form with Microsoft PowerApps.

I have a login action (Web API2) that is called:

```
SampleAPI.AuthLogin({UserName:UserNameTextBox.Text, Password:PasswordTextBox.Text})
```

This is working great. The Login method is returning a `json web token` which should be passed in all following requests. Is this possible?

Futhermore, when clicking on the `Login` button, a new screen should appear. (Using `Navigate`).

So how can I set the result of `AuthLogin` as the `Authentication Header` in all following http requests?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  I'm not sure what aspect of what you are trying to do is causing you grief.

I'm going to guess it is holding on to the json web token that is returned.  I'm guessing you would like the equivalent of a global variable to hold this value?  PowerApps does not have global variables, but it does have global collections.  Use the [Collect function](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-clear-collect-clearcollect/) to store the value in a collection that you can then access from anywhere in the app.  You can view collections in your app with the File menu.

If you don't need a global variable, as a variable scoped to the screen will suffice, then you can use a [context variable](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/working-with-variables/#create-a-context-variable) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to add a login level to the app. Is it possible to pass an entry from a collection in another http header when making a rest full request?